# Div placement at proper position

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a div which is visible in some scenarios. Below that div i have a next button. when that div is not visible the next button seems at the end. How can i tackle this situation? i want the next button to come at the place of the hidden div.

```
<div ng-show="(currentQuoteQto.requestType===constants.ssoQuote || currentQuoteQto.bu === constants.frNsQuote) && currentQuoteQto.status === constants.ssoPendingApproval
                      && (!currentCustomers[quoteRequest.contractingPartyIc01].onlineApproval ||
                      (currentQuoteQto.additionalDocuments && currentQuoteQto.additionalDocuments.length>0))" style="text-align: left; margin-left: 70px; margin-top: 25px" >
            <span translate>qrDetail.uploadDocuments</span><br>
          <span ng-repeat="additionalDocument in currentQuoteQto.additionalDocuments">
                {{$index + 1}}.{{additionalDocument.documentName}}<br>
            </span>
            <span ng-show="!currentCustomers[quoteRequest.contractingPartyIc01].onlineApproval">{{currentQuoteQto.additionalDocuments.length+1}}.<span translate>qrDetail.signedOrderForm</span></span>
            <div style="float: right" attachments show-Button=true attachments-data="quoteRequest" is-quote=true></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div style="text-align: right;margin-bottom: 40px;float: right">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <button class="bouton_action"
                 ng-click="showBundleAdditionalInformation()"
                 ng-disabled="!visibilityOfNextButtonForBundle()"
                 translate>button.next
    </button> </td>
    <td> <button class="bouton_action"

                 ng-show="visibilityOfSubmitButtonForBundle()  "
                 ng-click="setBundleOption();manageOrderRejection(false);manageQuoteRejection();"
                 ng-class="{bouton_action_l_pushed:inProgress.submit}"
                 translate>button.submitQuote
    </button> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please use https://jsfiddle.net/ to send us your code, At first glance you have a missing <div> tag in you HTML

Comment: Your buttons are inside table tag which causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a redundant closing `</div>` tag right before the following element

```
<div style="text-align: right;margin-bottom: 40px;float: right">
```

Remove the redundant tag and see how it goes.